# Entity Framework Code First Reverse Engineering of stored procedures

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5

I found an interesting stuff like this
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d. That could generate `POCO` objects as well as their configurations from database like in `database-first` approach.
Is there any tool to generate `stored procedures` signatures as well as POCO classes for `code-first` ?

Comment: Not sure about `stored procedures`, but with `code-first` approach you are supposed to write POCO, isn't it ?

Comment: If you did code-first, you'd already have the POCO classes and Stored Procedure signatures...

Comment: @Ehssan i have a database with huge amount of stored procedures.. so i need to import them automaticly